# What is filter pushdown optimization?

Tags: sql, algorithm, apache-spark, data-structures, data-science

Could you please bring some examples?

Answer (score 2):

First, find a proper definition [here](https://engineering.dynatrace.com/blog/optimizing-spark-queries-with-filter-pushdown/) for "Filter Pushdown":

> One way to prevent loading data that is not actually needed is **filter pushdown** (sometimes also referred to as predicate pushdown), which enables the execution of certain filters at the data source before it is loaded to an executor process. This becomes even more important if the executors are not on the same physical machine as the data.

Note that:

> In many cases, filter pushdown is automatically applied by Spark without explicit commands or input from the user. But **in certain cases, users have to provide specific information or even implement certain functionality themselves, especially when creating custom data sources**, i.e. for unsupported database types or unsupported file types.

Now, you can find a simple example in [databricks](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3741049972324885/4201913720573284/4413065072037724/latest.html). In this example, you can find that the order of select and filter can be optimized in regards to the query execution performance.